# Session state persistence in flask

Tags: kubernetes, flask

I have a flask-based chat application hosted on kubernetes. This app is connected to a db.

For every user/session, the app is supposed to query the db first and filter attributes that belong to the particular user's id. I read about kubernetes' session affinity to handle this but is there a better way to do this?

What if I have another frontend app which sends the user's message to my app? How can I send the session name (or token?) back to the frontend so that, every time a new user comes, a new pod is launched and each pod preserves this new state?

If my question sounds ambiguous or needs more clarity, do let me know